# Zip files using ZipFiles

Tags: c#

say if I have the following:

```
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
      zip.AddFile("C:\\ReadMe.txt");
      zip.AddFile("C:\\7440-N49th.png");
      zip.AddFile("C:\\2008_Annual_Report.pdf");        
      zip.Save("C:\\Files\\ZipFiles\\Test.zip");
    }
```

What I am confused on is that when I open up the zip file,
I it goes to C: first then I have to click on Files then I have to click on ZipFiles to see what is in the zip file.

Why doesn't it just open up the files I added when I click on the zip file?

Comment: If you're expecting a folder to automatically open containing the newly-zipped files, I don't see anything in your code that does that.

Comment: What library are you using for creating zipfiles?

Comment: If you're using that WiX stuff that some of your previous questions referenced, I'm afraid that I'm having a little bit of trouble finding adequate documentation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using DotNetZip? and do you mean you want to add the files to the root of the zip file?  If so, maybe you're trying to do

```
zip.AddFile("C:\\ReadMe.txt", "");
```

with the second string being the path you add it to in the zip(empty string if root).

Comment: Hi Sam I am, question - what I need to do beyond what I have posted is to dynamically create a list of files from the server and then show it to the user in unzip form so that they can store it locally Any way to do this without first storing it on the server and then opening it up. The user will most likely save the files that are unzipped locally on their machine

Comment: @WebDev If you're using dotnetzip, I believe that it is possible to unzip the file to a `MemoryStream` instead of to disk, and then you can get the data from the `MemoryStream`  You'd have to read up on the documentation and/or make use of what intellisence gives you for more details.